# how to fix star ratings hover in css

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I have a ionic mobile application. One of the many modules in the app is the review and ratings. By implementing such module, I added stars in which a user can click whether he wants to rate a certain user by tapping from one to five stars.

The problem here is that, once the user chooses a certain star, for example 5, then taps other parts in the app, the stars will be gone.

[image]

[image]

And if the user taps other than the star rating, the star chosen will be gone. How to fix such an error?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rating">
   <!-- <ion-icon name="star"></ion-icon> -->
   <span (click)="rate(5)">☆</span>
   <span (click)="rate(4)">☆</span>
   <span (click)="rate(3)">☆</span>
   <span (click)="rate(2)">☆</span>
   <span (click)="rate(1)">☆</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
page-review {

  .rating {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .star {
    // after: '\f2fc<br>\f2fc \f2fc \f2fc \f2fc';
  }

  .rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
  }

  .rating > span:hover:before,
  .rating > span:hover~span:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
  }

  .rating>span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.1em;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #F2AF01;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .review-description {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
}
```

Comment: please somebody help me. ive been debugging for days already but i cant seem to find a solution :(((

Comment: If people are going to help you they will, asking like that makes the question seem desperate, makes people think you think you're more important than you are, and is usually associated with low-quality, non-([MCVE]) questions.

Comment: sorry if i sound desperate :(

Comment: Well it's understandable. Just wanted to let you know it might not be recieved well.

Comment: Can you make a plunkr or anything with your code?

Comment: Please show your JavaScript-Code.

Comment: i think i cant give you a fully functional code in plunkr since it has a lot of dependencies which i need to import.

Comment: hi TheFronzenOne. no javaScript code involved. purely typescript and its only communicating the database and how many stars were choosen. i think the problem is within the CCS code

Comment: I tried to reproduce your behaviour, but for me it worked fine, when i click it call a `rate` function and logs the number, but the stars won't remain painted. Are you manipulating your stars via JS too? Are there other CSS code that can be interfering? That's why we need  a plunkr to help you.

Comment: helllo again. ya the problem is that the stars wont remain painted. im am not manipulating my stars via typescript it just logs the number of stars and put it into datbase. there are no other css code that can be interfering since thats the only css code for that page

Comment: i really appreciate you helping me gabriel. it gives me hope

Comment: link to code https://jsfiddle.net/c1k25ptg/

Comment: hi gabriel i added a link for the code you were asking sorry if its late

Comment: Sorry i didn't see the code before, was coding a solution. If it works don't forget to accept it as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the stars to remain full (or painted) you just need a CSS class, couple properties in your .ts file and Angular's `[ngClass]`.

HTML:

```
<div class="rating" (mouseenter)="isHover = true" (mouseleave)="isHover = false">
  <!-- Since you're using rtl to make it work the ngClass is also rtl. -->
  <span (click)="rate(5)" [ngClass]="{'full-star': rating >= 5 && !isHover}">☆</span>
  <span (click)="rate(4)" [ngClass]="{'full-star': rating >= 4 && !isHover}">☆</span>
  <span (click)="rate(3)" [ngClass]="{'full-star': rating >= 3 && !isHover}">☆</span>
  <span (click)="rate(2)" [ngClass]="{'full-star': rating >= 2 && !isHover}">☆</span>
  <span (click)="rate(1)" [ngClass]="{'full-star': rating >= 1 && !isHover}">☆</span>
</div>
```

`ngClass` will add a class if the condition inside of it is true, you can have multiple classes and conditions inside the curly braces and they need to be `{'class': condition}`.

The `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` are Angular events, they set `isHover` to true or false. `isHover` is used so when the mouse is hovering the rating stars it doesn't ramains painted. Without it if you select 5 stars, for example, and hover in the first stars all stars remain painted and it leaves a sensation that the rating is not working, baaaaad UX.

Now to your .ts file, just need to add two property:

```
export class YourPageClass{
  public rating: number = 0; // you may already have a rating property.
  public isHover: boolean =  false;

  constructor(){}

  rate = (r) => (this.rating = r);
}
```

I'm assuming you already have a rating property whose'll hold the rating value when the user click the star, if so just use your own rating property inside the `rate()` and inside the `[ngClass]`.

Add this class to your SCSS file

```
.full-star:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
}
```

That's it, this way you'll be able to achieve this effect of the star remaining full/painted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works. OMG!! thank you very muchhhh gabriel barreto!!!! my God bless you. thank you thank you

Comment: @Jennica You're welcome, if you need anything i'm here to help.

Comment: hi gabriel. can i ask another question under this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48852750/accessing-data-in-firebase-database 

its all about accessing data in firebase