# Accessing data in firebase database

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

So basically,I have a web application that uses firebase database. and I am having a hard time on how to access the `encircled` ones?

here is my code:

```
 function getDataFirebase() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        refReview.on("value", async function(snap){
            var data=snap.val();

            console.log("awdaw",data);

        })
    })
 }
```

[image]

Comment: The output you are showing is of `user` or `data` in console.log(). There are two console whose output you have pasted

Comment: sorry i updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over snapshot returned from firebase to get values inside the object.

```
function getDataFirebase() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        refReview.on("value", async function(snap){
            let rootkey = snap.key
            console.log(rootkey)
            snap.forEach(snapshot => {
                let childKey = snapshot.key
                console.log(childKey)
                Object.keys(snapshot.val()).map(k => {
                  console.log(snapshot.val()[k])
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

This case falls when we don't know the value of generated timestamps from firebase as child nodes.

Comment: its gives me the whole jason. how do i access certain data? like the child key of root key?

Comment: Map through the keys of json object and get the child values. Please check edited code

Comment: works. thank you very much. may i ask if theres another way?

Comment: yes using [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: can you demonstrate it to me if its okay?

Comment: sir can i ask last question. how do i access the root key?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165373/discussion-between-himanshu-and-jennica).